# Bash, is subshell output implicitly quoted

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In the following example

```
for f in *
do
    res=$(ls -la "$f")
    echo "$res"
done
```

Is this the correct way to use quotes? I know I should always quote the variable, but is the subshell output implicitly quoted?

Comment: Command substitutions follow the same rules as parameter expansion: you don't need quotes on the rhs of an assignment.

Comment: The right-hand-side of a  variable assignment is subject to tilde expansion.  If you don't want tilde expansion, then you should quote it.  For example, `r=~/.bashrc` will expand to `/home/john1024/.bashrc` but `r="~/.bashrc"` will not.

Comment: @John1024 That's true for literal "~"s on the right-hand side of an assignment, but not if "~" is in the output of an expansion. That is, `r=$(something that prints '~/.bashrc')`, will put a literal "~" in the value of `$r`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, that is correct: in variable assignments, tilde expansion is done _before_ command substitution, not _after_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The output from command substitution (`$()`) is not implicitly quoted:

```
$ for i in $(echo "foo bar"); do echo $i; done
foo                           
bar
```

The loop above splits the unquoted output along words. We can prevent this behavior by quoting the result:

```
$ for i in "$(echo "foo bar")"; do echo $i; done
foo bar
```

However, when assigning a variable, as in your example, the result of the subshell is not split, even without quotes:

```
$ baz=$(echo "foo bar")
$ echo "$baz"
foo bar
```

Unlike StackOverflow's syntax highlighting, the shell understands quotes inside command substitution, so we don't need to escape nested quotes:

```
$ baz="foo"
$ echo "$(echo "$baz $(echo "bar")")"
foo bar
```

Comment: The syntax in your example for loop is broken. And this is actually my question, how to correctly nest the quotes to quote the variable given to a subshell, and output of the subshell

Comment: The syntax is correct. The second example demonstrates how to nest quotes. The shell understands quotes inside of command substitution, so you don't need to escape the inner quotes.